# Tooltip cut off by floated container

Tags: css, hover, css-position, css-float

I have an element that shows on hover. But it is cut off by a floated element:
[image]

The center of the table scrolls horizontally.

How would I get the element to show over all other elements, preferably without any javascript?

I am using 3 different tables, which I prefer to keep. I know it doesn't fully make sense to have an element of the unfloated center table show above the floated elements. But these tips would just show when hovered, so it seems like a reasonable thing.

```css
.fulltable {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.colors {
  float: left;
  box-shadow: black 3px 0px 3px -4px;
}

.totals {
  float: right;
  box-shadow: black -3px 0px 3px -4px;
}

.data_table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.data,
.colors,
.totals {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
}

.tooltip .tip {
  min-width: 120px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #444444;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip:hover .tip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fulltable">
  <table class="colors">
    <thead>
      <th>COLOR</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Blue</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="totals">
    <thead>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="data_table">
    <table class="data">
      <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="tooltip">1
            <div class="tip">
              <span>Don't cut me off.</span>
              <i></i>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should postion your tooltip element above the elements in the code it should be displayed over. the parent element should be relative, the tooltip element or its wrapping element absolute.

here an example how it could work:

```
<style>
.fulltable {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

.colors {
  float: left;
  box-shadow: black 3px 0px 3px -4px;
}

.totals {
  float: right;
  box-shadow: black -3px 0px 3px -4px;
}

.data_table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.data,
.colors,
.totals {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
}

.tooltip .tip {
  min-width: 120px;
  border:1px solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #444444;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 99999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip:hover .tip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<div class="fulltable">
  <div class="tooltip">1
    <div class="tip">
      <span>Don't cut me off.</span>
      <i></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="colors">
    <thead>
      <th>COLOR</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Blue</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="totals">
    <thead>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="data_table">
    <table class="data">
      <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1
          </td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that data is now positioned absolute so doesn't scroll with the rest of the table.

Comment: you have an example with big elements to see the scrolling? the absolute position should be fixed to the relative parent element so it shoud be scrolling along with the table on a page. Or is it scrolling in overflowing content?

Comment: Yes, the scrolling is an important part of this. The real code has a similar design, with a very large scrollable table in the middle of the left and right floated tables.